# How can I delete the correct file without running the loop multiple times in js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm having this problem when uploading multiple files. That is when I upload multiple images in the 1st input file and delete an image in the 1st position, I lose all the files in that 1st input file, even the 2nd input file is the same, but when I delete an image uploaded in a certain input file only affects the scope of that input file, other input files are not affected. When I console.log(key) of the first element with class name .remove I clicked, it ran 5 times (because I uploaded 5 images). Is it because of the for loop outside? Can you explain and help me fix this problem ?

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.js" integrity="sha256-a9jBBRygX1Bh5lt8GZjXDzyOB+bWve9EiO7tROUtj/E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="field" align="left">
    <div class="upload__files-wrap"></div>
    <input type="file" class="files" accept="image/*" name="hinhanh1[]" multiple />
  </div>

  <div class="field" align="left">
    <div class="upload__files-wrap"></div>
    <input type="file" class="files" accept="image/*" name="hinhanh2[]" multiple />
  </div>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

```
input[type="file"] {
  display: block;
}

.upload__files-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 -10px;
}

.imageThumb {
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
}

.pip {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  position: relative;
}

.remove {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 24px;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.remove:after {
  content: "\2716";
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
}
```

```
$(function () {
  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    $(".files").each(function (key) {
      var files_name_arr = [];
      var dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();

      $(this).change(function (e) {
        for (let file of e.target.files) {
          if (!files_name_arr.includes(file.name)) {
            dataTransfer.items.add(file);
          }
        }

        this.files = dataTransfer.files;

        for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
          let file = this.files[i];

          if (!files_name_arr.includes(file.name)) {
            let fileReader = new FileReader();

            fileReader.onloadend = (function (file) {
              return function (e) {
                $($(".upload__files-wrap")[key]).append(
                  '<div class="pip">' +
                    '<img class="imageThumb" src="' +
                    e.target.result +
                    '" title="' +
                    file.name +
                    '"/>' +
                    '<br/><span class="remove"></span>' +
                    "</div>"
                );

                files_name_arr.push(file.name);

                let input_index = key;

                // HERE GOES A BIG PROBLEM !!!
                $($(".upload__files-wrap")[key])
                  .find("span.remove")
                  .each(function (key) {
                    $(this).click(function (e) {
                      console.log(key);
                      // console.log(this);
                      // let pips = $(this).parents('.upload__files-wrap').find('.pip').toArray();
                      // console.log(pips);
                      let selectedPip = $(this).parent(".pip");
                      // console.log(selectedPip);
                      // let index = pips.indexOf(selectedPip[0]);
                      // console.log(index);

                      dataTransfer.items.remove(key);
                      files_name_arr.splice(key, 1);
                      selectedPip.remove();
                      $(".files")[input_index].files = dataTransfer.files;
                    });
                  });
              };
            })(file);

            fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
          }
        }
      });
    });
  } else {
    alert("Trình duyệt bạn không hỗ trợ File API");
  }
});
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/duyphi522001/pen/ExGWbrW

Comment: Please don't delete your [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77074668/1169519) and then repost the same question.

Comment: I think your `key` variable might be the problem? Once you do `dataTransfer.items.remove(key);`, the index of the rest of the items after the one you just removed, will decrease by one. But your click handlers on the rest of the `span.remove` elements will still be using that original `key` value.